# Redis spring boot how can I see values from command line

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I'm working with spring boot and Redis, I have this simple structure

```
public class Redis {    
    @Id
    private String key;

    private Integer value1;

    private Integer value2;
}

@Repository
public interface RedisRepository extends CrudRepository<Redis, String> {
}


redisRepository.save(new Redis("myKey", 1, 2));

127.0.0.7:6379> KEYS *
1) "myKey"
127.0.0.7:6379> type "myKey"
set
```

I don't see any values, how can I see the values from command line, in this case I want to see 1 and 2. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use RedisRepository, spring does not use a simple key, value pattern to store object data in redis. It uses the hash operation of redis. For example, I have a model `RedisModel.java`

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@RedisHash("redis_model")
public class RedisModel {
    @Id
    String key;
    Integer value1;
    Integer value2;
}
```

Also a repository `RedisRepository.java`

```
@Repository
public interface RedisRepository extends CrudRepository<RedisModel, String> {
}
```

I saved a RedisModel with RedisRepository like this

```
redisRepository.save(new RedisModel("key",1,2));
```

But when I monitor the log of redis I see that

```
1603128368.772046 [0 127.0.0.1:37776] "DEL" "redis_model:key"
1603128368.781117 [0 127.0.0.1:37776] "HMSET" "redis_model:key" "_class" "com.bimurto.springdataredis.RedisModel" "key" "key" "value1" "1" "value2" "2"
1603128368.782503 [0 127.0.0.1:37776] "SADD" "redis_model" "key"
```

So if you want to see the values in redis command line you have to use Hash Operation Commands of redis. If you want to get all values of your object, use `HGETALL`. For example

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL redis_model:key
1) "_class"
2) "com.bimurto.springdataredis.RedisModel"
3) "key"
4) "key"
5) "value1"
6) "1"
7) "value2"
8) "2"
```

if you want the value of a single key , then use `HMGET` like

```
127.0.0.1:6379>HMGET redis_model:key value1
1) "1"
```